# How do I turn Model.order('attributes desc') into a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have

```
  @microposts = Micropost.order('votes desc').paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

and it works but I want to convert it to a scope such that I can call

```
  # @microposts = Micropost.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

and have the same output.

In micropost.rb, I have

```
  scope :order => 'votes desc'
```

but that doesn't work. The error I receive is:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:order=>"votes desc"}:Hash
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope :ordered, order("votes desc")
```

This also might be a possible valid case for a default_scope too.